# LS estimator for the population variance

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have a random sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ from an unknown  population, and I want an estimator,
$\hat{\mu}$, for its mean. One possible approach is to choose the $\hat{\mu}$ that minimizes the squared differences between the sample and the estimator to get:
$$
\frac{d \sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \hat{\mu})^2}{d \hat{\mu}} = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \hat{\mu} = 
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j}{n}.
$$
A familiar answer. Suppose I wanted a similar (LS) estimator for the population variance,
how would I set that up? I don't think I've seen a LS estimator for the variance outside the linear model context.

Comment: Yes, you would just take your estimator to be the sample variance (i.e. plug in estimator)

Comment: The (average) squared difference is the estimator which follows directly from zhis method:  $\hat \sigma^2=\frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n (X_j - \overline{x})^2$. This estimator is biased.

Comment: @Andrew. But why? There is at least some logic behind x-bar as a LS estimator.

Comment: @callculus42: I know what it is, but how did you arrive at it through the LS method?

Comment: "LS method" is ill-defined here.  What are the squares that you intend to sum to minimise?  I can think of at least two different SS that can be used.

Comment: @user10354138: Precisely my point -- what would you sum and minimize?  But if you have two SS that can be use perhaps you would share them.

Comment: If you want to use an estimator which minimize squared difference you use $\hat \sigma^2=k\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (X_j - \overline{x})^2$. If you additionally want an unbiased estimator you use $\hat \sigma^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (X_j - \overline{x})^2$, since $\mathbb E(\hat \sigma^2)=\sigma^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i\neq j$, we have $\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_j)^2=2\operatorname{Var}X$, so we might want to consider estimator $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ minimising the "loss" function
$$
L:=L(\sigma^2;X_1,\dots,X_n)=\sum_{i\neq j}[(X_i-X_j)^2-2\sigma^2]^2.
$$

Indeed, we can check
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}(\sigma^2)}=-4\sum_{i\neq j}[(X_i-X_j)^2-2\sigma^2]
$$
so at the minimiser $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ we get
$$
\widehat{\sigma^2}=\frac1{n(n-1)}\sum_{i<j}(X_i-X_j)^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum_i(X_i-\bar{X})^2
$$
which agrees with the usual population variance estimator $s^2$.

The above example is of course a special case of a family of loss functions, given by estimating the mean using $k\leq n$ subsamples from $X_1,\dots,X_n$ ($k=1$ in the above).  You could also consider the $l\leq n$ subsample means and how far that deviate from the $k$ version, etc.  So for example, in the case when $\{k,l\}=\{1,n\}$ you get
$$
L=\sum_i [(X_i-\bar{X})^2-\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2]^2.
$$

Anyway, you can see that there are at least 2 different SS that we can consider, for the $k=l=1$ and $k=l=2$ provided $n\geq 4$ and we restrict considerations to the case of disjoint subsamples.  The $k=l=1$ case don't give terms such as $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ but they appear for $k=l=2$ ($L=\sum_{k_1,k_2,l_1,l_2}[\frac14(X_{k_1}+X_{k_2}-X_{l_1}-X_{l_2})^2-\sigma^2]^2$).